# I can't add OnClick functions to my button in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, onclick, buttonclick, textmeshpro

I can't add `OnClick` functions to my Text Mesh Pro button. The menu is not what it used to be. Any solution?

[image: img]

I removed and re-imported the TMP package but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the 'Debug' version of the property inspector.  Turn off Debug and you will see the OnClick handlers.

Look for the three dots to the far right side of where you have the Inspector window docked.  Click on it and choose 'Normal'

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was in debug mode. Thank you so much.